# Keyboard.Listener interfering with tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Hello I am building tkinter application and need to create a hotkey for the application. When I use Keyboard.Listener with the code below my tkinter app doesn't show up at all. the Keyboard.Listener code works fine on its own but I can't see why it is effecting my tkinter app when I apply it
Hotkeys code that works on its own is

```
# Hotkeys snip

COMBINATIONS = [
    {keyboard.Key.shift, keyboard.KeyCode(char='a')},
    {keyboard.Key.shift, keyboard.KeyCode(char='A')}
]
current = set()

def on_press(key):
    if any([key in COMBO for COMBO in COMBINATIONS]):
        current.add(key)
        if any(all(k in current for k in COMBO) for COMBO in COMBINATIONS):
            screenshot()

def on_release(key):
    if any([key in COMBO for COMBO in COMBINATIONS]):
        current.remove(key)

with keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()

#End of hotkeys snip
```

The code including the tkinter code is below but there is no error message the gui just doesnt show up with the hotkey code there aswell

```
import os
import datetime
import pyautogui
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import font
from PIL import ImageTk,Image
from os import listdir
from pynput import keyboard
from os.path import isfile, join

master = Tk()
master.config(height = 1800,width = 1800, bg = "chocolate1")



# Hotkeys snip


COMBINATIONS = [
    {keyboard.Key.shift, keyboard.KeyCode(char='a')},
    {keyboard.Key.shift, keyboard.KeyCode(char='A')}
]
current = set()

def on_press(key):
    if any([key in COMBO for COMBO in COMBINATIONS]):
        current.add(key)
        if any(all(k in current for k in COMBO) for COMBO in COMBINATIONS):
            screenshot()


def on_release(key):
    if any([key in COMBO for COMBO in COMBINATIONS]):
        current.remove(key)



with keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()




#End of hotkeys snip

mypath = "C:\\Users\\link\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\python stuff\\screenshot example\\All snapshot images"
onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir(mypath)]


#Opening of images and resizing
#C:\Users\link\OneDrive\Desktop\python stuff\screenshot example\All snapshot images
mainview = Image.open("C:\\Users\\link\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\python stuff\\screenshot example\\All snapshot images\\" + str(onlyfiles[-1]))
mainview = mainview.resize((800, 800), Image.ANTIALIAS)
mainview =ImageTk.PhotoImage(mainview)

myFont = font.Font(family='Big Caslon',size = 9)
#Lables

picture_box = Label(height = 800,width = 800,image = mainview)


#Buttons

button_1 = Button(height = 3,width=29,text= "Take a screenshot", bg =  "chocolate3",activebackground = "white",relief = RAISED, command = screenshot)
button_2 = Button(height = 3,width=29,text= "Screenshots by time", bg =  "chocolate3",activebackground = "white",relief = RAISED,command = open_win2)
button_3 = Button(height = 3,width=29,text= "screenshot folders", bg =  "chocolate3",activebackground = "white",relief = RAISED,command = create_secondwindow_button)



#widget placment

button_3.place(x=100,y=500)
button_2.place(x=100,y=400)
button_1.place(x=100, y = 300)
button_1["font"]= myFont
button_2["font"]= myFont
button_3["font"]= myFont
picture_box.place(x=800, y=100)



master.mainloop()
```

I would really appreciate some advice on this thanks a lot

Comment: Please show the tkinter code as well. We cannot see where the error is when you just show us the keyboard code.

Comment: Hi @bad_coder I have edited in the full tkinter code. I apologise that I didn't do it earlier as I didn't know what was relevant.

Comment: `listener.join()` is not going to return until your Listener exits - and I don't see any code that could possibly cause the Listener to exit.  So the remainder of your program is unreachable.  You probably don't want that `with` statement at all - just create the Listener at the start, and manually close it at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Why to use keyboard as there is a built in function in tkinter that is better than keyboard

**It is called bind()**
Imagine my window name is **root**
So In Order to bind... I Could Use **root.bind()**

Here I have to pass two arguments first is the event...If It is a key I can simply pass it like this
Imagine the key I need to bind is the letter a. So I Do

```
root.bind('a', '''type function name here''')
```

And Make sure in the function you have to do this

```
def function_name(event):
    # whatever you have to do
```

Actually, there are tutorials on youtube which are better than mine.